# Fabric8 Openshift-client 6.5.1 return forbidden

Tags: java

I config my openshift-client as follow.I try to use this client to do something.Like list configmaps

```
OpenShiftClient adapt = new KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(new ConfigBuilder()
                .withMasterUrl("http://xxx:8080")
                .withNamespace("default")
                .withTrustCerts(true).withUsername("admin").withPassword("admin")
                .build()).build().adapt(OpenShiftClient.class);
        
ConfigMapList list = adapt.configMaps().list();
```

But operation return this error:

configmaps is forbidden: user "system:anonymous" cannot list resource...

I can use username and password to login openshift,and do some operation.But cannot use openshift-client to do this.I can do this at fabric8 6.5.0,but at version 6.5.1 will  throw exception.How can I do?